# Solving Integral with two substitutions

Tags: integration

In trying to solve$\int_1^\sqrt{2}x^3(x^2-1)^4dx$ I did two substitutions. The first was $x=\sec\theta$ and the second was $u=\tan\theta$. I ended up getting $\frac{7}{24}$ as my answer but the actual answer is $\frac{11}{60}$. Why might I be wrong? Do trig substitutions not work in this case. The two main integrals in my work are:

$$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}(\tan^2\theta+1)(\tan^5 \theta)(\sec^2\theta)d\theta$$

$$\int_0^1u^7+u^5du$$

Comment: Unless you post the details of your work, we can't begin to guess what might be wrong or right.

Comment: @TedShifrin Gotta head over to take my math final pretty soon so thats why I don't have time since the work for this problem was very long

Comment: Well, I did it following your recipe and got the "actual answer."

Comment: @TedShifrin For the theta integral my bounds were $\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $0$. For the $u$-integral my bounds were $1$ and $0$. Maybe I made a mistake here.

Comment: That's correct. If one denominator is $10$ and the other denominator is $12$, we're going to end up with some number of $60$ths.

Comment: @TedShifrin I am not seeing a 10 or 12 in my work. Maybe my integrals are written wrong? I posted them above.

Comment: Isn't $(\sec^2\theta-1)^4 = \tan^8\theta$? You've skipped too many steps for me to nail it down.

Comment: @TedShifrin Oh I think you got it! Thanks

Comment: We cannot check your work if you don't show it !

Comment: Read the integrand as $\frac12(x^2-1)'(x^2-1+1)(x^2-1)^4=\frac12(x^2-1)'(x^2-1)^5+\frac12(x^2-1)'(x^2-1)^4$.

Answer (score 1):

**Another method of solving:** (*I think it is the most simpliest method to solve the integration*)

Let $~u=x^2-1\implies du=2xdx~~$and$~~x\to1\implies u\to 0~$and$~x\to\sqrt 2\implies u\to 1~$ . So $$I=\int_1^\sqrt{2}x^3(x^2-1)^4dx$$
$$I=\dfrac12\int_1^\sqrt{2}(2x)x^2(x^2-1)^4dx$$
$$I=\dfrac12\int_0^1 u^4 (u+1)~du$$
$$=\dfrac12\int_0^1  (u^5+u^4)~du$$
$$=\dfrac12\left[\dfrac{u^6}6+\dfrac{u^5}5\right]_0^1$$
$$=\dfrac12\left[\dfrac{1}6+\dfrac{1}5\right]$$
$$=\dfrac{11}{60}$$

### -------------------------

**Relating to your query:**

Let $~x=\sec\theta\implies dx=\sec\theta~\tan\theta~d\theta~~$and$~~x\to1\implies \theta\to 0~$and$~x\to\sqrt2 \implies\theta\to \dfrac{\pi}4~$.

$$I=\int_1^\sqrt{2}x^3(x^2-1)^4dx$$
$$=\int_0^{\dfrac{\pi}4}\sec^3\theta~\tan^8\theta~\sec\theta~\tan\theta~d\theta$$
$$=\int_0^{\dfrac{\pi}4}\sec^4\theta~\tan^9\theta~d\theta$$
$$=\int_0^{\dfrac{\pi}4}\sec^2\theta~\tan^{\color\red 9}\theta~(1+\tan^2\theta)~d\theta$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: For the $$\int_1^{\sqrt{2}}2x^3\left(x^2-1\right)^4\, dx \tag 1$$
the result is $\color{red}{\frac{11}{30}}$ and not $\frac{11}{60}$. In fact the $(1)$ is equal:

$$=2\cdot \int _1^{\sqrt{2}}x^3 (x^2-1)^4dx=2\left(\int _1^{\sqrt{2}}x^{11}dx-\int _1^{\sqrt{2}}4x^9dx+\int _1^{\sqrt{2}}6x^7dx-\int _1^{\sqrt{2}}4x^5dx+\int _1^{\sqrt{2}}x^3dx\right)$$
i.e.

$$=2\left(\frac{21}{4}-\frac{62}{5}+\frac{45}{4}-\frac{14}{3}+\frac{3}{4}\right)=\color{red}{\frac{11}{30}}$$

After:

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\left(\tan ^2\left(θ\right)+1\right)\tan^5\left(θ\right)\sec ^2\left(θ\right)dθ$$
applying correctly the substitution $t=\tan\theta$, you will have $\cdots =\int _0^1t^7+t^5dt=\dfrac{7}{24}$.